# Replace String Code Fast Effiecient

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, performance, replace

Last few days left i make a script for string replacement with all of yours help. Now i am testing on my all sites but on some site shows stop script popup error in FF, in chrome Kil Page error it seems my script use lots of browser resource when replacing so i need your professional coding touches that make string replace script more efficient fast optimized here is my code:

```
function avid_number_setup(){

var avidno = '(800).123.1234';

var match_tollandlocal = avidno.match(/800|822|833|844|855|866|877|888|899/gi);

if(match_tollandlocal != null){

 //alert('TollFree number');

 (function($){

   $('*').each(function(i){

   $('body').html($('body').html().replace(avidno,'<span id="avidtoll">AvidTrak Tracking Number</span>'));       

  })

 })(jQuery)

}

if(match_tollandlocal == null){

 // alert('Local number');

 (function($){

   $('*').each(function(i){

   $('body').html($('body').html().replace(avidno,'<span id="avidlocal">AvidTrak Tracking Number</span>'));       

   })

  })(jQuery)

 }  

} 

avid_number_setup();
```

Need your helps/tips to make my string replace code more fast and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
$('*').each(
```

Does something for every element on the page. This takes a lot of time and is not needed. Remove it.

Comment: Thankx friend its help but not much, my script replace takes too much time :(